# What is a term for the long-term emotional "climate" of a relationship?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for a word or phrase to describe the overarching "mood" of a relationship across its existence, rather than at one specific time. For example, if the "mood" of the relationship at a given time is analogous to the "weather" in the sense that it describes the immediate, how can one describe the emotional "climate" that spans a longer time?

From [NOAA](https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/news/weather-vs-climate):

> Whereas weather refers to short-term changes in the atmosphere, climate describes what the weather is like over a long period of time in a specific area. Different regions can have different climates. To describe the climate of a place, we might say what the temperatures are like during different seasons, how windy it usually is, or how much rain or snow typically falls.

Example sentence: At that moment, the mood between them was tense, even though in general the ________ of the relationship was carefree.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the description and example sentence, a good word is [**nature**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nature):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **1 a** : the inherent character or basic constitution (see [CONSTITUTION sense 2](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/constitution)) of a person or thing : [ESSENCE](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/essence)
>        // the *nature* of the controversy
> **1 b** : [DISPOSITION](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disposition), [TEMPERAMENT](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/temperament)
>        // it was his *nature* to look after others
>        — F. A. Swinnerton
>        // her romantic *nature*
> **3** : a kind or class usually distinguished by fundamental or essential characteristics
>     // documents of a confidential *nature*
>     // acts of a ceremonial *nature*

Used in the example sentence in the question:

> At that moment, the mood between them was tense, even though in general the *nature* of the relationship was carefree.

Answer (score 1):

The word **"nature"** comes to mind.

According to *Webster's New Dictionary of Synonyms* p. 839:

> **nature** may suggest inherent, essential characteristics rather than superficial, ostensible, or tentative ones

*This means that you can use "nature" to describe the "climate" but "mood" for the "weather."*

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider ***tenor***

Defined by [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/amp/english/tenor) as:

> the general meaning, character, or pattern of something:  *What was the general tenor of his speech?*

In your sentence:

> At that moment, the mood between them was tense, even though in general the tenor of the relationship was carefree.

Answer (score 0):

The two JBs have suggested *nature*, which is indeed an excellent word.

However I would suggest *the relationship itself* is carefree - you might say *the relationship is in general **characterised by being** carefree*, or simply *though their relationship **was generally carefree***.

Answer (score -1):

An *emerging term/slang* is using the word **meta** as a noun to represent the general popular theme/ideas of something, typically a video game.

For example,

> In 2014, the Minecraft meta was all about building castles, expansive minecart tracks, and cactus farms.

So you could potentially refer to it as the meta of their relationship.

> The meta of their relationship was carefree.